# Scipy: Difference between ellipk and ellipkm1

Tags: python, scipy

I was wondering what are the difference between the function ellipk and ellipkm1 from the scipy  special module.

With the documentation we learn that ellipk calculate the elliptic integral of the first kind and ellipkm1 calculate the same but for parameter which is around 1.

I then plot the following graph, see [here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=939962figure2.png).

Finally I don't see from which value we have to use ellipkm1 instead of ellipk.

Somebody have an answer ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, `ellipkm1(x)` is equivalent to `ellipk(1-x)`.  `ellipkm1` is used for computing the function at values very close to one. For example, suppose you want to evaluate `ellipk` at `x = 1 - 1e-30`.  In fact, you can't, because with double precision floating point, `1 - 1e-30` is equal to `1`, so `ellipkm(1 - 1e-30)` will return `inf`.  Instead, evaluate `ellipkm1` at `1e-30`.

Here's a demonstration of evaluating the integral at `1 - 1e-30`.

```
In [30]: eps = 1e-30

In [31]: 1 - eps  # eps is smaller than 1 ULP, so 1-eps == 1.
Out[31]: 1.0

In [32]: ellipk(1 - eps)  # Of course, this gives inf.
Out[32]: inf

In [33]: ellipkm1(eps)  # This is the value we want.
Out[33]: 35.925070756030571
```